# Create large XML in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, large-files

I found that I could write each line separately to file:
but writing root node () manually is ugly and error prone. Do you have any idea how do it better?

I would like to convert large text (about 1TB) file to XML file.
For simplification let's say that xml structure is:

```
<lines>
    <line>line1</line>
    <line>line2</line>
    ...
    <line>lineN</line>
</lines>
```

Naive version is doing it like that:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("input.txt")
    .getLines
    .map(l => <line>{ l }</line>)

val xml = <lines>{lines}</lines>
scala.xml.XML.save("output.xml", xml, "UTF-8")
```

but it leads to OutOfMemoryError because composing lines into the root node leads to expanding whole stream.
I found that I could write each line separately to file:

```
val writer = new FileWriter("output.xml")

writer.write(
  """|<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     |<lines>
     |""".stripMargin('|'))
lines.foreach(l => {
    scala.xml.XML.write(writer, l, "", false, null)
    writer.write('\n')
})
writer.write("</lines>")
writer.flush
```

but writing root node (`<lines>`) manually is ugly and error prone.
Do you have any idea how do it better?

Comment: Why do you say that writing the root node the way you are writing it is error prone?

Comment: Agree with @Eduardo: your present solution gets the job done - it is unclear what you expect for improvement.

Comment: In this particular example it might looks fine. But if I would like to add some attributes to root node I will have to escape values manualy. What is more, if I have some more complicated structure (eg entities node and inside it companies and persons nodes)
I will end up creating persons and companies nodes manualy. I wonder if scala has some api or external library to create xml from stream data.